# Why is the <nav> Navbar element placed outside a container?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I'm curious if anyone knows why the semantic Navbar `<nav>` element is housed outside the outer `<div class="container">` ?

From the [Bootstrap Navbar docs](https://getbootstrap.com/components/#navbar)

```html
    <nav class="navbar navbar-default">
        <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
            <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            ...
        </div>
        ...
    </nav>
```

My understanding (I thought) was that, in order for Bootstrap to, erm, *bootstrap*, everything had to be in a container > row > col.

Having used it a bit now, I understand there are caveats and "it's not always that simple" so I'm trying to faithfully perform the ball-achingly tedious work involved in digging into my app's front-end, while also understanding what I'm doing.

Is the answer just as simple as (my guess), `<nav>` is a "special" element created to live "outside" normal containers due to their special use case (particularly in the case of site/app-wide navigation)?

Steps taken on my own:

1. Reviewed 10+ "Similar questions"
2. Spent time on getbootstrap.com
3. Checked w3schools
4. Googled `"<nav>"`

Comment: nah - a container would adding padding to either side - with `<header>`, `<nav>` and `<footer>` it's best to leave them outside the container so they span the full width of the page

Comment: can you please make a working fiddle so we can look at your problem closely

Comment: @ThisGuyHasTwoThumbs that makes sense, if I can figure it out I'll accept that s an answer.

Comment: Not a question specific to any particular project, above is code pasted in from the Navbar docs on getbootstrap.com.  I noticed it and couldn't think of/find the answer (I'm working on my front-end skills, worked more on the back-end so far...)

Comment: @IanDaley yeah - it's more for design then convention :)

Comment: _“My understanding (I thought) was that, in order for Bootstrap to, erm, bootstrap, everything had to be in a container > row > col”_ - for the bootstrap grid system to work - yes. But a navigation is usually not using the grid system to begin with; mostly you have a navigation that is independent from the grid, followed by the main page content that might be using the grid.

Answer (score 0):

“My understanding (I thought) was that, in order for Bootstrap to, erm, bootstrap, everything had to be in a container > row > col” - for the bootstrap grid system to work - yes. But a navigation is usually not using the grid system to begin with; mostly you have a navigation that is independent from the grid, followed by the main page content that might be using the grid. – CBroe 1 min ago

This answered my question.  Thanks.

Comment: The real reason is not so much because the nav does not use the grid system, rather because the nav bar bar needs to be full-width , but its components aligned with the rest of the page elements, hence within a child container.

Answer (score 0):

This enables the navbar to stretch to full width - the .container within it constrains the nav elements themselves. Look at [https://getbootstrap.com/examples/theme/] you'll see the dark navbar strip is full-width.

There's nothing stopping you from making multiple full-width sections each with their own .container div inside. See [https://getbootstrap.com/examples/jumbotron/] for an example - the .jumbotron also has a child .container but the background stretches to full width.

Also, there is nothing special about a .navbar element that means it must sit outside the container, as this example shows: [https://getbootstrap.com/examples/carousel/].

So use a container where you want to set max width and make sure the grid system works.